# Using ? wildcard with ls

Tags: bash, scripting, wildcard, ls

I'm trying to use the ? wildcard to display only 1 character files, and ?.* to display 1 character files with extensions.

what works:

`cd /mydir`

`ls ? ?.*`

I'm trying to use this in a shell script so therefor i cant use "cd"

What i'm trying to get to work

```
ls ? ?.* /mydir
```

and it gives me the output:

```
ls: cannot access ?.*: No such file or directory
```

I've also tried:

```
ls /mydir ? ?.*
```

which gives me the exact same output as before.

Comment: `ls /mydir/? /mydir/?.*` should work... otherwise, why can't you `cd` in your script?

Comment: By the way, here `ls` is useless, `echo /mydir/? /mydir?.*` will do as well, if your goal is only to show the files.

Comment: @ZeddAlmighty: You will get `No such file or directory` with `ls` if there is no file with 1 char in name with extension in the directory. Better avoid ls

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf `ls` is not entirely useless, it depends. For example, it outputs files on separate lines, if run in a pipe.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf that worked thank you. and to answer your question. It's being piped to wc and stored in a variable. anubhava but the i know there are files for both results.

Comment: Why would you pipe the output of `ls` to anything? `ls` is not meant to be piped at all. The only purpose of `ls` is to print the content of the directory to your terminal, nothing else. Please, tell us what your real task is, and we'll give you better ways to accomplish it `:)`.

Comment: @user2719058 `ls` is not meant to be used in a pipe, see my previous comment.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Can you give an argument why you think `ls` is meant for interactive use only? By the way, "not meant to be used for FOO" is distinct from "better not used for FOO". I would be curious about both.

Comment: @user2719058 Please spend some time reading [this wonderful document](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) written by the most knowledgeable guys I know.

Comment: im in college for linux administrator and 1 of my current classes in shell scripting. My teacher is just going over basic stuff. And, my current assingment is to get the number of files in the tmp directory of our class server, the number of files that end in .log and the number of files that only have 1 character names and store the data in a file and then display the stored data to the user. I know it's stupid, but it's my assignment.

Comment: @user2719058 [And also this one](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Practices#Don.27t_Ever_Do_These)

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Ok, it breaks with non-standard names. The most serious breakage can be mitigated by making `ls` quote its output; but if you really want to cope with all valid pathnames - that is, every character under the sun except `NUL` bytes and `/`, then I guess you probably don't want to program in shell anyway. Point taken, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write `ls ? ?.* /mydir`, you're trying to display the files matching three distincts patterns: `?`, `?.*`, and `/mydir`. You want to match only `/mydir/?` and `/mydir/?.*`, hence this command: `ls /mydir/? /mydir/?.*`.

Edit: while this is a correct answer to the initial question (listing `/mydir/?` and `/mydir/?.*`), OP wanted to do this to parse the output and get the file count. See @gniourf_gniourf's answer, which is a much better way to do this.

Answer (score 4):

From a comment you wrote:

> im in college for linux administrator and 1 of my current classes in shell scripting. My teacher is just going over basic stuff. And, my current assingment is to get the number of files in the tmp directory of our class server, the number of files that end in .log and the number of files that only have 1 character names and store the data in a file and then display the stored data to the user. I know it's stupid, but it's my assignment.

I only hope that they don't teach you to parse the output of `ls` in college... it's one of the most terrible things to do. Please refer to these links:

- [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls(1)](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)
- [Don't ever do these](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Practices#Don.27t_Ever_Do_These)

The solution you chose

```
ls /mydir/? /mydir/?.* | wc -l
```

is broken in two cases:

- If there are no matching files, you'll get an error. You can fix that in two ways: use `shopt -s nullglob` or just redirect `stderr` to `devnull`.
- If there's a newline in a file name. Try it: `touch $'a.lol\nlol\n\lol\nlol\nlol'`. LOL.

The proper bash way is the following:

```
shopt -s nullglob
shopt -u failglob
files=( /mydir/? /mydir/?.* )
echo "There are ${#files[@]} files found."
```

Comment: +1, this is the best answer. Sometimes detailed answers get no love on SO

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The comment detailing the reason OP wanted to do this wasn't precised when I answered.

Answer (score 0):

`cd` works perfectly within a shell script, use it. For minimal impact on the script, I would use a subshell:

```
( cd /mydir && ls ? ?.* )
```

That way, you don't change the current working directory of the script (and neither `$OLDPWD`, which would be clobbered with `cd /mydir; ...; cd -;`).

Comment: Often useful. But I'd add a warning that then you have the risk of trying to set variables somewhere in the subshell, and be surprised when they 'disappear' when further along in the englobing shell ^^

Answer (score 0):

While `ls` seems like an obvious choice, `find` is probably more suitable:

```
find /mydir \! -name "." -a \( -name "?" -o -name "?.*" \)
```